# Segfault when passing data using MPI Windows (MPI_Put)

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi

I am trying to figure out how to use MPI to work with matrices.

I have a 3x6 matrix filled with zeros and am running code with 3 threads. `0` is the main one, `1` writes to the first row of the matrix in columns from 1 to 3 ones, and `2` stream writes to the second row in columns 4-6 of two.

I pass these formed parts to the main thread (at 0), I get the correct result, but after that a memory error is output to the console.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Can you please tell me what is my mistake?

```
program test

    Use mpi

    Implicit None

    integer :: process_Rank, size_Of_Cluster, ierror = 0, win, size_s, n = 6
    integer:: i , j
    integer:: start, target_count = 9
    integer :: mtx(3,6)
    integer(kind = MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) :: nbytes = 4

    !input matrix
    do i = 1,3
        do j =1,6
            mtx(i,j) = 0
        end do
    end do

    Call mpi_sizeof( mtx, size_s, ierror ) !Get the size of a matrix element
    call MPI_INIT(ierror)
    call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size_Of_Cluster, ierror)
    call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, process_Rank, ierror)

    !create windows
    if(process_Rank == 0) then
        call MPI_WIN_CREATE(mtx, size_s *6 * 3 * nbytes, 1, MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, win, ierror)
    else
        call MPI_WIN_CREATE(mtx, size_s * 6* 3*nbytes,1, MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, win, ierror)
    end if

    CALL MPI_Win_fence(0,win,ierror)

    if(process_Rank == 1) then
        !fill 3 columns of the first row with ones
        start = 0
        do i = 0,3
            mtx(process_Rank,i+start) = process_Rank
        end do

        CALL MPI_PUT(mtx, size_s*3*6, MPI_INTEGER, 0, start * nbytes, target_count, MPI_INTEGER, win, ierror)

        !print mtx
        print *, process_Rank, ' put = '
        do i = 1,3
            print *, ''
            do j = 1,3
                write(*,fmt='(g0)', advance = 'no') mtx(i,j)
                write(*,fmt='(g0)', advance = 'no') '  '
            end do
        end do
    end if

    CALL MPI_Win_fence(0, win,ierror)

    if(process_Rank == 2) then
        !fill the last 3 columns of the second row with twos
        start = 3
        do i = 1,3
            mtx(process_Rank,i+start) = process_Rank
        end do

        CALL MPI_PUT(mtx(1:3,4:6), size_s* 3 *6, MPI_INTEGER, 0, 3 * 3 * nbytes, target_count, MPI_INTEGER, win, ierror)

        !print mtx
        print *, process_Rank, ' put = '
        do i = 1,3
            print *, ''
            do j = 4,6 
                write(*,fmt='(g0)', advance = 'no') mtx(i,j)
                write(*,fmt='(g0)', advance = 'no') '  '
            end do
        end do
    end if

    CALL MPI_Win_fence(0, win,ierror)

    ! print result
    if(process_Rank == 0) then
        print *, 'result = '
        do i = 1,3
            print *, ''
            do j = 1,6 
                write(*,fmt='(g0)', advance = 'no') mtx(i,j)
                write(*,fmt='(g0)', advance = 'no') '  '
            end do
        end do
    end if

    CALL MPI_Win_fence(0, win,ierror)
    CALL MPI_WIN_FREE(win, ierror)
    call MPI_FINALIZE(ierror)

end program test
```

Console:

```
1 put =
1 1 1
0 0 0
0 0 0 

2 put =
0 0 0
2 2 2
0 0 0 

result =
1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 2 2 2
0 0 0 0 0 0

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0 0x7fd4447bcd01 in ???
#1 0x7fd4447bbed5 in ???
#2 0x7fd4445f020f in ???
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Primary job terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 0 on node alm-VirtualBox exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Firstly please give us *exactly* the code you are using, the above won't compile. Secondly you have checked it with all run time error checking turned on? For gfortran this is -fcheck=all. This should pick up at least one error - there may be others, but fix the easy ones first.

Comment: @IanBush sorry, accidentally added a comma to line 7. Fixed the post. Now there is the actual code that is compiled.

Comment: Also what is a "matrix chat" as mentioned in the title? I have no idea

Comment: @IanBush I have updated the title

Comment: The first step should always be to find out at which line the crash happens. for that you should always compile your code with debugging options enabled. E.g. for gfortran `-g -fcheck=all` or for Intel `-g -check`. The `-g` will turn some of the nonsense addresses `0x7fd4447bcd01` into actual code locations.

Comment: You can also use debugging `print` or `write` messages to locate the place of the crash. Place them in various parts of the code and watch whether they are executed or not. Another extremely useful tool is `valgrind`, but with MPI you must be careful to run it as `mpirun -n ... valgrind ./my_process`. The `-g` option is also very useful when using valgrind.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `-fcheck=all`, which Ian Bush suggested to you in the first comment under your question, you will get the reason for the error immediately and you do not have to wait many hours for feedback on the internet. I got:

```
At line 38 of file mpi_wins.f90 Fortran runtime error:
Index '0' of dimension 2 of array 'mtx' below lower bound of 1 


Error termination. Backtrace:
#0  0x7f7ed3e75640 in ???
#1  0x7f7ed3e76185 in ???
#2  0x7f7ed3e7652a in ???
#3  0x4010e4 in test
        at /home/lada/f/testy/stackoverflow/mpi_wins.f90:38
#4  0x401e78 in main
        at /home/lada/f/testy/stackoverflow/mpi_wins.f90:3
```

You are indexing your `mtx` array using the process rank, but the array is defined to start from `1`.

```
integer :: mtx(3,6)
```

However, MPI ranks start from `0`, not from `1`.

Also notice that the backtrace now contains a better code location thanks to the `-g` compiler option.

Comment: This is marked "community wiki", is there a reason for this?

Comment: @IanBush I do not want to be harvesting rep from trivial answers. One cold maybe mark it as a duplicate of some other question with a one-by off error, but who knows. It is also hard to find. Or maybe 
"Not reproducible or was caused by a typo" but I am worried it might be a wrong thing to do.

Comment: And also, I hoped it might motivate some to actually upvote it, when I receive no rep anyway, so that the question does not get regularly bumped to the the front page as not-answered...

Comment: Problem is to answer it properly requires more investment of time than I have got at the moment - there's a few things wrong, and I would want to check I properly understood the implications of MPI_PUT on an array slice before I answer as well.